# Question about the totient function and congruence classes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function, congruences

If $x,y$ are integers where $x | \varphi(y)$ does it follow that the reduced residue class modulo $y$ divides evenly into congruence classes modulo $x$?

For example, if we look at $y=35$ and $x = 3$.  In this case, we have $\varphi(35)=24$ and we see that there are:

- $8$ elements $\{3, 6, 9, 12, 18, 24, 27, 33\}$ that are congruent to $0$ modulo $3$
- $8$ elements $\{ 1, 4, 13, 16, 19, 22, 31, 34\}$ that are congruent to $1$ modulo $3$
- $8$ elements $\{ 2, 8, 11, 17, 23, 26, 29, 32\}$ that are congruent to $2$ modulo $3$

Is this always the case?  If not, can you provide a counter example?

Thanks very much!

-Larry

Comment: Note that you are missing $27$ in the $0\mod 3$ class. My intuition tells me the statement is true, but I haven't got a proof of it (yet).

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  I added 27 to the above.

Comment: I took the liberty to ask a follow up... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640232/divisors-of-the-totient-function-and-congruences

Comment: Thanks for doing that.  Very interesting exchange.  I also reasked my question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/640014/48606 and modified it slightly based on your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$2|\varphi(12)=4$, but of course all four elements are odd.

Comment: I took the liberty to ask a follow up... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640232/divisors-of-the-totient-function-and-congruences