# Divisors of the totient function and congruences

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, cyclic-groups

Based on the question [Question about the totient function and congruence classes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639756/question-about-the-totient-function-and-congruence-classes), I would like to ask two new questions:

### Question 1

Does it hold that if $k\mid\varphi(n)$ then the elements of the multiplicative group $\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}(\Z/n\Z)^*$ maps via $\psi_k$ defined by $\psi_k(m)=m\mbox{ mod }k$ into a subset of $\Z/k\Z$ in a way so that the pre-images of each $\alpha\in\mbox{Im}(\psi_k)$ have the same size.

### Question 2

Which additional conditions must $k,n$ where $k\mid\varphi(n)$ satisfy in order for $\psi_k$ defined in the previous question to be surjective?

In the original question you can see that [user11977](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/121430/user11977) points out that $\psi_2$ is not surjective for $n=12$.

### My thoughts, the Carmichael function

So far my thoughts are that this has to do with the Carmichael function and the product of cyclic groups connected to the multiplicative group of integers $(\Z/n\Z)^*$. [(see this link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Exponent)

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by the natural homomorphism $\psi_k$. $1$ is the identity element of $({\mathbb Z}/n{\mathbb Z})^*$ and it is not the identity element of ${\mathbb Z}/k{\mathbb Z}$, so your definition makes no sense.

Comment: But your new version is still not a homomorphism. Remember that you are mapping a multiplicative group to an additive group. I am very sceptical whether there is any such natural homomorphisms in general.

Comment: @DerekHolt: And just to point it out specifically: it is NOT a homomorphism, but it need not be in order for the question to make sense...

Comment: OK, so what about $n=9$, $k=6$, we get $\psi_k:1,2,4,5,7,8 \mapsto 1,2,4,5,1,2$

Comment: @DerekHolt: That is a good one! That is actually a much more interesting answer to the original question than the one that is there...

Comment: @DerekHolt: Perhaps the additional restriction to have $\mbox{gcd}(k,n)=1$ would imply pre-images of equal size? I will have to think some more, maybe my current question is ill posed anyway. Thanks!